# Firestore get length data disappear in flutter stream

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I make a chat using firebase firestore.

So. I tried express not read count in the Chat list.

But, Initially the number appears, but it changes to null data.

I don't know Why data chage null data?

```
body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chatRooms')
        .where('emails', arrayContainsAny: [user?.email]).snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      var chatLists = snapshot.data?.docs;

      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Something error...');
      }

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Text('is Loading...');
      }
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: chatLists?.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (chatLists?[index]['currentMsg'] != null &&
              chatLists?[index]['currentMsg'] != "") {
            var list = List.from(chatLists?[index]['members']);
            var member = '';

            if (loginUser['userName'] != null) {
              for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (list[i] != loginUser['userName']) {
                  member += list[i];
                }
              }
            }

            return ListTile(
              title: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(member),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 20.0,
                  ),
                  ChatLength(docId: chatLists![index].id, uid: user!.uid),
                ],
              ),
              subtitle: SizedBox(
                  height: 40.0,
                  child: Text(
                    chatLists[index]['currentMsg'],
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  )),
              trailing: Text(
                tmFormmater(chatLists?[index]['currentTm']),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff999999),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ChatScreen(
                      docId: chatLists![index].id,
                      title: member,
                    ),
                  )),
            );
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        },
      );

      return Container();
    },
  ),
```

```
class ChatLength extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatLength({super.key, required this.docId, required this.uid});

  final String docId;
  final String uid;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('message_read')
          .doc(docId)
          .collection('message')
          .where('userId', isNotEqualTo: uid)
          .where('read', isEqualTo: false)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data?.size);
        if (snapshot.data?.size != null) {
          return Container(
            child: Text('${snapshot.data?.size}'),
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
===== Debug console ====
flutter: 1 
flutter: null    //  Data changes to null immediately
```

message_read collection structure

> message_read -> documentId -> message -> documentId -> field(userId(chat writer), read)

1. I'm trying get a snapshot data from firestore.
2. And I put the imported data into the text.
3. But Data changes to null immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `snapshots()` the code is not just reading the data once, but then continues listening for changes to the data. So the two values you see mean that the `snapshots()` stream was triggered twice, the first time with a single message - and the second time without any messages.

My educated guess is that your code changes the `read` value of the document after it gets it, since it has now displayed that message to the user. But doing so means the document no longer meets the criteria of your query, so the `snapshots` stream gets a new event without that message in it.

Consider using a different mechanism for the query, for example I usually use a timestamp to determine what messages to show. Step by step:

- Ensure each message document has a timestamp field.
- For each user store (either in the database or in local storage of the app) when they last started the app.
- Then request from the database the messages since they last started the app.
- Make sure to start the query *before* you update the timestamp value, otherwise you'll never get any results.

Comment: Message_read collection update are modified when enter the chat room and has data.

And It is displayed as null data, but the collection data is not updated.

Comment: "Message_read collection update are modified when enter the chat room and has data" Please show the code for that in your question. --- "but the collection data is not updated" Please edit your question to show code and logging output that shows that the database update succeeds on that side, and a screenshot of an non-updated document in the database to show that it failed on that side.

Comment: I find new wrong this problem.  I tried to count the other side chat. I write 


.where('userId', isNotEqualTo: uid)
.where('read', isEqualTo: false)  

this query result is null  (I need this query's result)
.where('userId', isEqualTo: uid)
.where('read', isEqualTo: false)  

this query is has data but It's mine chat counter.


Is there a problem with the query?

Comment: I solved this prolem. When I added firestore index. Thank you for comment.